# Cross-browser compatibility problem with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My site is incompatible with IE. How can I fix this problem?

[image: Firefox]
[image: IE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have separate css style for your ie so load the css on the browser identification, socailly ie6 have problem with floating div's threat them different , positioning with absolute and relative is the key.

ie 8 behave different in firefox nested divs inherit css from parent but ie8  need you to specify the css for that div

use :
<
br clear="all" />

between floating div's to clear last floating div effect on next div's

Comment: dear amin :) thanks. where are you from ? are you from iran? (چاکریم!)

Comment: yes dear shahin, i'm iranian glad to help iranian too. another issue with ie6 is problem with png which you can fix using java script or css . be successful dear

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell for sure without looking at the code. I would g guess that you either have an issue with your floats as previously suggested. Search clearfix as a possible remedy which you could apply to the container holding the floated assets.

The second thing I would look for is an unclosed tag ie missing `</div>` or really many open tags could break and cause it to look like this in IE

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a css float issue to me. IE handles floats differently than other good browsers. A quick google will get you tonnes of info on that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn to create websites in a cross-browser friendly manner from the scratch code. This question is too vague to be asked in a specific manner.

Try to use less of those "hacks" and stick with standard-compliant XHTML/CSS coding. Starting with a good CSS framework (such as text reset css files etc. that float around the web) is a good idea. I often use the 960 grid system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick fix and can use javascript you may find this interesting:
http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/.
It's a script that "upgrades" Internet Explorer so that it will act as a newer version.

I hope this helps you,
Alin

Comment: i did download the source. how can i use it now?

Comment: Just read the instructions on the page. You have there all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you coded the floats right ( between sets of floats) and maintained the width of each element then here are some fixes that can help you solve your issues:

• Double margin for floating element – add “display: inline;” to div.

• Floats not aligned – add width (not auto) to element.

• Double padding – add “display: inline-block;” to div.

• Negative margin image cut off – add “position: relative;” to div.

Some or all of them may help you.

It'll be more easy to help if you provide us with a live view of your site.